# Drive sends an almost-daily "1 file is now available offline" notification

Tags: nexus-5, google-drive, push-notifications

On my second device (Nexus 5), I keep getting the same notification from Drive almost every morning. When I click on it, the app opens its main screen without marking the file that I was notified about. Funny thing is, I haven't received such notifications on my main device (Pixel 3).

What is this notification about? Can the notification be triggered from the update of a some backup file?

[image]

Comment: Try clearing **Drive** app's cache. If it doesn't work, clear it's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the files that I've uploaded recently are being flagged as "Available offline", which downloads them to the device and the app shows this notification when a download is completed. I suppose that's an intended behavior, even though I've never flagged any of my files as "Available offline" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I think unchecking the "make recent files available offline" setting in the Google Drive app did the trick.

I'm using Google Drive v2.20.261.01.40 on a Google Pixel 3a with Android 10 (build QQ3A.200605.002).

Comment: On my android I found this setting in the individual sheets and docs apps, not the drive app.